# ngModel changes, ngModelChange is not called

Tags: angular

```
<input type="number" style="width: 100px" [(ngModel)]="trait.userMinimum" (ngModelChange)="setThresholds()">
```

The model gets changed by the below code and is reflected on the screen but then ngModelChange is not called. I want it to be called regardless of it being changed elsewhere or being a property or whatever reason. If the model changes it calls ngModelChange.

```
  <p-slider [(ngModel)]="trait.userMinimum" 
    [style]="{'width':'100%'}" 
    [min]="trait.min"
    [max]="trait.max"
    class="ui-g-8"></p-slider>
  <span class="ui-g-2">{{trait.max}}</span>
```

To clarify ngModel works as expected, I move the slider the number changes, I type in the number the slider changes. The only thing that doesn't work is the slider changes and the model change is not called in the input.

Comment: You should use `DoCheck` incase `onChange` not fire. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck

Comment: hmm I tried that but it was extremely non performant

Comment: Please create plunker that demonstrates your problem

Comment: @ZackLucky, did you find what was wrong with this? I'm stuck in kind of similar situation

Comment: @RumitParakhiya I think David's answer solved it for me, splitting getter and setter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
//This is a **two way** binding, so below code will not take effect
[(ngModel)]="trait.userMinimum"  
(ngModelChange)="setThresholds()" //This will not be fired
```

The solution is to change as below, and remove the "()" so that the get and set are separate:

```
[(ngModel)]="trait.userMinimum" ---> [ngModel]="trait.userMinimum"
```

Comment: No way, I was wondering if this would work, so then I would just need to do (ngModel)="setThresholds()" to call the method?

Comment: not working I have exact same code : `<TextField hint="hhint" [ngModel]="con_no1" (ngModelChange)="saverange($event)"</TextField>` and then inside class `private con_no1: any;saverange(newValue) {console.log(newValue);}`

Comment: Not working same problem @ishandutta2007 did you find any solution

Comment: @ZackLucky - did this work by changing [(ngModel)] to [ngModel]???

Answer (score 5):

**[(ngModel)]** is used for the two way binding like from and to View and component,To use the `ngModuleChange` we need to split it **[()]** (Banana into the box) than its become the ***Property Binding*** **`[]`** and the ***Event Binding*** **`()`**

Inside the **component.html**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter number" 
   style="width: 100px"
  [ngModel]="trait.userMinimum" 
 (ngModelChange)="setThresholds($event)"/>
```

And inside the  **component.ts** file , we need to use these `setThresholds` method which get the value from `Editext` like below

```
 setThresholds(getValue)
 {
   console.log(getValue)     
         /**
         * DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
         */
 }
```

There is also another way to use by the `getter` and `setter` property to get and set the data from the view

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be more like a comment, but putting it as an answer to make it more visible. I got the same error, but unfortunately the above answer did not work. There was also an error in the console which I ignored earlier `ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.` Fixing this issue caused the problem to be fixed.

In a nutshell what I did was adding an **additional attribute** called **`name`**  to the input.

```
<input type="number" name="userMinimum" [(ngModel)]="trait.userMinimum" class="form-control"  (ngModelChange)="setThresholds($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to split `[(ngModel)]`, you can use standard `(input)` event.

Although you cannot get the full input value, it is great for additional actions.

Answer (score -2):

Get valuechanges on that field:

```
@ViewChild('nameOfField') nameOfField: any; 

this.nameOfField.valueChanges.subscribe((v: any) => {
    this.onChange(v);
}
```