# Angular - Detect <input /> value change with one way binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, oneway

I have this

```
<input [value]="SomeModel.ValueFunct()" readonly="readonly"/>
```

**It works!** the value displayed changes when the function return value change.

**How can i detect if the value change?**

**UPDATE:**

Using:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) : void{
```

or

```
(gModelChange)="function($event)"
```

or

```
(change)="function($event)"
```

with

```
[ngModel]="SomeModel.ValueFunct()"
```

doesn't work when the function change, only if user change the input *(but in this case is readonly)*

Plunk:

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Rj3NjtcGXTo9upt9?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview
.

.

*Same unsolved question:*

[ngModel changes, ngModelChange is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126961/ngmodel-changes-ngmodelchange-is-not-called)

Answer (score -1):

So, instead of binding function directly, bind the actual value in the input tag. And in your typescript file, write the ngOnChanges() lifecycle event and detect this change.

So, if you want one-way data binding, then

```
<input [ngModel]="variable">
```

In your .ts file, import the `OnChanges` and `SimpleChanges` from `angular/core`

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if(changes[variable]) {
          // Perform your actions.
        }
    }
```

If you want to work with the data changed in input field in html while working with one way data binding, you have to use (ngModelChange) as below :

```
<input [ngModel]="variable"(ngModelChange)="function_to_fire_on_model_change($event)">
```

Comment: I already tried that!, but doesn't work. the event doesn't get fired if the "variable" is a function.

Comment: <input [ngModel]="class.class.class.function()" (ngModelChange)="function_to_fire_on_model_change($event)">

The value change without problem, but the event doesn't get fired. I even tried (change) and SimpleChanges with the function.

Comment: I can solve my problem creating a custom event that get triggered when the value inside the function change or manually bind the value or create a custom component or a loop watching a change or a lot of possibilities! but I guess there is a simple way! that's why I'm looking for the native approach.

Comment: Please create sample fiddle for this.

Comment: did you have time to review it?