# Angular input box value not updated from ngModelChange event when value is cleared by Ctrl+A and prev value is same as suppose to be new value

Tags: html, angular

I am using simple `ngModelChange` event on `input` box where updated value is passed on event and updated back after some operations.

```
<input placeholder="" #TestInput="ngModel"
        name="TestInput" 
        [(ngModel)]="testInput" 
        (ngModelChange)="onTestInputChange($event)" >
```

and in component

```
  testInput: string;
  onTestInputChange(event) {
    this.testInput =  this.testInput === ''
      ? 'cat' 
      : this.testInput==='tiger'
        ? this.testInput 
        : 'lion';
  }
```

Steps:

1. When input is anything, it will updated to 'lion';
2. When I select input by Ctrl+A and delete, value is updated to 'cat' for first time.
3. As the value is already 'cat', if I perform step 2 again, it should update to 'cat' again, but it is not updating, surprisingly `testInput` is updated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqpcjx

Also tried `change` event also, no luck.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using two-way binding on your ngModel, so both your ngModel and ngModelChange are interacting with the model change event. You can read more from this answer:

[ngModel changes, ngModelChange is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126961/ngmodel-changes-ngmodelchange-is-not-called)

Looking at that answer, you'll see they recommend removing the two-way binding. If you don't need two way binding for ngModel, make it only settable by changing the `[()]` to just `[]`. But in your example this doesn't give the desired effect.

What I recommend is simply using the DOM level change event to run your event listener, so change `(ngModelChange)` to simply `(change)`.

```
<input placeholder="" #TestInput="ngModel"
    name="TestInput" 
    [(ngModel)]="testInput" 
    (change)="onTestInputChange($event)" >
```

-- EDIT --

The above is not actually correct. The real issue is to do with when the view is updated – as long as ngModel believes it hasn't changed, it doesn't update the view (even though we can see for ourselves that the visible value of the input is different).

So when you set the value to `''` the value of `testInput` becomes `'cat'`. You delete again, and `testInput` is set to `'cat'` again. NgModel believes nothing has changed so the view is not updated (even though we see the change on the input).

You can force Angular to fix this by running `detectChanges` before testInput is reset to `'cat'`. To do this, you want to inject `changeDetectorRef`, like so:

```
import { Component, VERSION, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  testInput: string;

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef)  {
  }
  //issue is when testInput blank valus is assigned as 'cat' again,
  // but not updated in input element.
  onTestInputChange(event) {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.testInput =  this.testInput === ''
      ? 'cat' 
      : this.testInput === 'tiger'
        ? this.testInput 
        : 'lion';
  }
}
```

Now the view will be updated with every change to ngModel. Here's the fork:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bd2mu5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

That said, I still believe the `(change)` solution is better because it's more user friendly to wait for blur. Otherwise, they'll never even get the chance to type 'tiger' because it will always be switched to 'lion'.

Comment: `change`doesn't fire unless the input field is blurred, did you mean `input`? It doesn't work for the same reason `ngModelChange` does not work, surprisingly

Comment: Thanks @michael-beeson, but I tried `change` as well as `keyup` event, both are having same behaviour in this case and not working.

Comment: ah, I thought having it on blur would be a feature, not a bug, because it actually allows you to type in "tiger" for example.

Comment: Really? Not working even on blur? Look at this fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bd2mu5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html It replaces the empty input value with cat (but only on blur, or ENTER key)

Comment: Sorry, I worded that ambigiously, it does work with change and blurring the input, but the input event doesnt work for the same reason ngModelChange doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelBeeson Thanks it work with change, what I did earlier was kept `ngModelChange` as it is, and add `change` event, so it was not working. When I remove `ngModelChange` from html, it worked, was it strange behaviour or my mistake I am now confused..Thanks again

Comment: I looked into it more carefully to understand why your solution didn't work, and I've provided you with the answer in my edit. That said, I think using `(change)` or `(blur)` is still a better solution for usability

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered a similiar question and iam still unsure as to why neither your solution nor `input` doesn't work.

To get the immediate result without first having to blur your input, you can reference your input element and change it's value during the `input` event.

```
<input placeholder="" #TestInput
         name="TestInput" 
        (input)="onTestInputChange(TestInput)" >
```

```
onTestInputChange(input) {
    input.value =  input.value === ''
      ? 'cat' 
      : input.value ==='tiger'
        ? input.value 
        : 'lion';
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gbchzy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: sorry, but we are supporting IE also, and `input` event doesn't work there sometime :), it worked with `change` event, the key is you cannot kept both `ngModelChange` and `change` in input, or it will break sometime.

Comment: Actually it does, however only for `text` and `password`. If you wanted the same behavior without the input event, you'd have to use a directive.